# How to get the Combined report of multiple threads when they are accessing the same URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am executing a test plan in which I have used two thread groups in which I have used multiple Selenium/WebDriver samples just for getting the URLs with the help of **getCurrentUrl()** function.

In the report, I have got the URLs for each different thread(Users) that is totally fine but besides this, **I also want the combined report of each same URL that different threads(users) are accessing to it.**

> Suppose for example :

We have three URLs and 3 threads(Users) in each thread group(2 thread groups I am taking).

1. www.abc.com
2. www.xyz.com
3. www.pqr.com

So here I am getting the individual report of each Url in dashboard report for each user ***but I want a combined report of `www.abc.com` for a total of 6 users (2 thread groups and each has 3 threads(users) so total it becomes 6) and similarly for the rest of the URLs.***

Can anyone please help me how can I do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), something like:

[image]

or

[image]

depending whether `Generate parent sampler` box is ticked or not.

More information: [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)

Comment: I am using the sample label through selenium/webdriver scripting to print the current URL of each request and with respect to that, each web driver sample is showing in the report for different user or thread but not like as you have done in your 2nd image. So what can I do in that case ??